# Interact with python interactive shell using popen

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute commands in the python interactive shell and print the output through popen.

I started with this code:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":

    process = subprocess.Popen('python',
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                shell=True)

    process.stdin.write('help()\n'.encode())
    process.stdin.flush()

    output = process.stdout.read()

    print(output)

    process.stdin.write('q\n'.encode())
    process.stdin.flush()

    output = process.stdout.read()

    print(output)

    process.stdin.write('exit()\n'.encode())
    process.stdin.flush()

    output = process.stdout.read()

    print(output)
```

However the execution is blocked at line `process.stdout.read()`.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 documentation says

**`read(size=-1)`**
Read and return up to size bytes. If the argument is omitted, None, or negative,
data is read and returned until EOF is reached. An empty bytes object is returned
if the stream is already at EOF.

Your `read()` is a blocking call, try reading with a size or try using `peek` to determine if there is content in the buffer before reading.